# Proper declaration of global C-constants in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, global-variables

I'm trying to declare and initialize global C-variables.

```
const int numberOfTickMarks = 6;
const double tickValues[numberOfTickMarks] = {500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000};
```

When I do this in my header file (before the `@interface`), I get a linker error. But when I do this in the `.m` file (before `@implementation`), things seem to work as desired.

Is the latter the accepted way to declare global constants for C/Objective-C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481554/global-variables-in-objective-c-difference-in-extern-and-top-of-m-file-declar?rq=1

Comment: The question is whether you want them for just one file or shared over multiple files. You are not going to #import a _.m_ file, so "the latter" (`const double` in the _.m_ file) would not suffice in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global variables should be declared like this in the header file:

```
extern const int numberOfTickMarks;
extern const double tickValues[numberOfTickMarks];
```

Without `extern`, linker errors are inevitable.

In the implementation file, you would have to define them again like this:

```
const int numberOfTickMarks = 6;
const double tickValues[numberOfTickMarks] = {500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000};
```

Comment: So basically you're saying I just have to add `extern` to the declarations I put in the header file.  Of course `numberOfTickMarks` is still undefined there, so can't be used for the length of the array. I'd like to make it so I have to change as little code as possible. Is there any way to allow the `numberOfTickMarks` in the definition of the array?

Comment: (Sorry, got declaration and definition mixed up.) Is there any way for the compiler to get the size of an array? If so, I could use that to *define*/set `numberOfTickMarks`.

Comment: `sizeof(tickValues)/sizeof(*tickValues)` = size of the array

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in a case where I have a "magic number" is a `#define`:

```
#define NUM_TICK_MARKS 6
```

It can go in the *.m* file, but if it is to be shared widely, I might put it in the *.pch* file.

**And by the way**:

The `numberOfTickMarks` is not necessary:

```
const double tickValues[numberOfTickMarks] = {500, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 8000};
```

The initializer says quite clearly how big the array is!

Answer (score 0):

Why not define them on the `main.m` file ?

```
type myVar;
```

And declare on the header, use:

```
extern type myVar;
```

#### Edit

By what you wrote on the comments, I think you need to use class variables. Since this resource is not available in objective-c, I see 2 alternatives:

1) Use c++ as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250088/1341626)

2) Use a shared instance, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5592395/1341626)

Personally, I'd go with number 2

Comment: Doesn't seem appropriate since the variables are proper to my viewController and not to the project as a whole.

Comment: than why use global variables ? Class and instance variables are what you should be looking for

Comment: Because I want them accessible to some static functions defined in the  viewController.m and proper to that viewController.

Comment: @JohnK Then why do you need them to be extern *at all?*

Comment: @H2CO3, where did I say I needed them to be extern?